# Trigger capture of screen using a mouse click

Tags: screen, shutter

Is it possible to tweak shutter in such a way that I can capture the image in my screen by simply clicking the mouse and not pressing enter on the keyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a default option in Shutter.

Easily:

- if you set selection to window, easily just click on the mouse on the window you want to take a screenshot of.
- If you choose user selection then once you setup the are you have to double click and thus you can take the shot.